# jquery click event on array of objects versus trigger click on single element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I understand jquery and have worked with it but I am by no means a pro thus this question.

I have a complicated jquery array object defined like this

```
var $elements = $([]);

$elements = $elements.add($protoElement.clone()

  .css({
   left: offset.left,
   top: offset.top,
   backgroundPosition: (bgLeft + 'px ' + bgTop + 'px')
  })
```

...

Later on I add to it a click event

```
 $elements.click(function() {

   ....

    var $element = $(this);

....
}
```

This is all code that I "inherited". I need to extend/change the code so that 
the click event is triggered by code (rather then by an explicit click) on a specific $element of the array $elements.

What is the best way to achieve that?

Will there be a conflict between the code click trigger for an element and the above click event handler?

Comment: What is that _specific_ element?

Comment: It is just like in your example below $elements.eq(2).trigger